# Is it a bad idea to let laptops directly perform CRUD operations on databases?

Tags: ado.net, connection, database-connection, ado

I have developed an Excel add-in that I pitched to my employer's IT department.  The add-in creates SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE SQL statements that are sent to a PostgreSQL database and any results (in the case of a SELECT statement) are returned to Excel to report on.

My team has been very impressed with this, but IT said that they don't allow laptops to perform CRUD operations directly on databases.  Instead IT has set up certain environments to do this.

Can someone tell me if IT's concern around laptops directly connecting to a database and performing CRUD operations makes sense?  Is this a valid concern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the laptops, their users and anybody else with access to them, the network connection, and the client software are all trusted, and you can always immediately push an update to the clients when the database structure inevitably changes in the future, then it's OK.

Otherwise it's not. The standard way would be to put some kind of service between the two that acts as a gatekeeper and defines the allowed operations on the database and who is allowed to do them. REST (or if you're enterprisey, SOAP) are two popular options. And don't send SQL over the wire in those cases.

With some database engines it might be possible in theory to let the users directly authenticate with the database and use the database's permission model to limit what they can do. For instance you could only allow users to execute certain stored procedures. But in practice that's probably more trouble than it's worth.

To be honest in practice it's probably not OK. That's too many things to trust at once.

Comment: Thanks, Matti!  I'm almost positive that all of the above are trusted, not to mention my add-in would be in a secure folder on my company's shared drive that I would have to give permission to users before they can access the add-in.  

But, let's say something above is not trusted.  Would prompting users to sign in be the service you're referring to?

Comment: Note that any user on the network could use different/hacked versions of the client software. Maybe that makes them untrusted users, maybe just power users. Better to not rely on checks built into client software for anything other than convenience.

Comment: @christopheralan88: I updated my answer with some popular service options. Some kind of authentication besides "they're in the network" is a very good idea from a security perspective. Signing in or single sign on could work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a valid concern. Someone could easily inject an SQL command into your database. They might be able to perform an operation that erases the entire database.

Say your software has this coed into itself: `"SELECT $var1 FROM TEST WHERE $var2"` and the user can modify var1 and var2. If they put `"date > 10; DROP *"` into var2 now your statement becomes `"SELECT $var1 FROM TEST WHERE date > 10; DROP *;"`

It is a little more complicated than that, but you should read up on [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: It's more than that probably. With SQL injection, you can "only" mess with parameters. With a direct SQL connection, you can completely make up your own SQL statements.

Comment: Yeah, just by looking at the database schema table they could view every table in the SQL database. They might even find ones related to something entirely different that they should have access to.

Comment: @Aaron It would be a concern assuming that the user they are signed in as has read privileges to that table or schema, correct?  The add-in signs them in to a certain user that has certain privileges.  The information_schema is not one of those.  Am I thinking about that correctly?

Comment: @Thilo I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but how does data access technology like ADO.NET prevent this?  It creates a SQL connection for data to be pulled into DataReader/DataTable/DataSet objects, correct?  And any changes are pushed from the DataSet to the database in the form of SQL, right?

Comment: @christopheralan88: You prevent this by having a three-tier architecture: There is a server between database and client application. The server talks to the database only in ways provided by the (server-side) programmer. It enforces permissions and does not allow the client to execute arbitrary queries.

Comment: For a two-tier application (client talks directly to database), you can try to lock down the permissions at the database level (also by providing stored procedures). But that approach is more limited and tedious (and dangerous if you make mistakes).

Comment: @christopheralan88 Limiting user access can help, but it is still risky to give them access without any kind of middle man. A 3-tier system would be great because it could act as a filter like Matt outlined in his answer.